# how to concat two strings in php which are in persian

Tags: php, utf-8, concatenation, persian

The question is that i have the string of:

```
$content=$rows["content"];
```

which i retrieved from the data base.The sting is in Persian.
i want to show the only 150 character.so i used:

```
$content=substr($content,0,150);
```

and to show that this still continues i need to show 3 dots: "..."
so i did:

```
$content.='...';
```

and when i show this string by echo, the 3 dots that i added will appear at the right of the last line.
but persian is from right to left, so the 3 dots needs to appear in left of the last line.

i tired this one two, but this one didn't worked too

```
    $content =iconv(mb_detect_encoding($content, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $content);
    $content=substr($content,0,150);
    $dot='...';
    $dot =iconv(mb_detect_encoding($dot, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $dot);
    $content.=$dot;
```

Comment: substr() isn't unicode aware, and treats strings as simple byte sequences. you CAN'T use it on unicode strings without mangling the text. that's why there's the whole `mb_*()` function set, including `mb_substr()`

Comment: try $content = mb_substr($content,0,150,'utf-8')

Comment: @MarcB thanks for your answer.but it's not working yet!

Comment: @Pooya thanks for your answer, I did as you said and it is still not working,the concatenation is right, or I have to make some kind of change in that one too?

Comment: try this $content.utf8_encode($dot) and see if it helps

Comment: internally php isn't unicode aware at all, and I doubt it'd obey the rtl/ltr of any particular language. you may just have to reverse the logic and substr from the end of the string, which in php is always on the "right" side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i simply added a p tag with rtl around the texts that i wanted to be shown this way. like this:

```
            <p dir="rtl">';
            echo $content;
            echo "...";
            echo  '</p>';
```